# Disabled button em CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, button, action

[below translated from translate.google.com]

I'm looking for the syntax of how to make a button disabled in CakePHP and I can not get a result; My application need to first save a field for a button to finish the whole process after another button. The first button is a submit and redirects to the same page. The second button performs a function of the controller and go to the next process. I want to prevent the user to go to the next procedure without saving the first; I already have a variable that defines whether it is safe or not, just do not know how to make the Finish button is disabled;

Button code:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok')) . " Finalizar",
        array('controller' => 'Questoes','action' => 'limparSession'),
        array('role' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-success', 'escape' => false)
    );
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria indo para translate.google.com, escrevendo a sua pergunta lá. Em seguida, copie / cole a versão em Inglês traduzido aqui em stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->button(
        $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok'))." Finalizar",
        array('type' => 'submit','onclick' => 'this.disabled=true;return true;',
        'class' => 'btn disabled', 'escape' => false)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the **disabled** class to your button:

```
<?php

    echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok')) . " Finalizar",
        array(
            'controller' => 'Questoes',
            'action' => 'limparSession'
        ),
        array(
            'role' => 'button',
            'class' => 'btn btn-success disabled',
            'escape' => false
        )
    );

?>
```

This is a **bootstrap** feature related to the given class.

If you want to do it *without* bootstrap:

```
<?php

    echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok')) . " Finalizar",
        array(
            'controller' => 'Questoes',
            'action' => 'limparSession'
        ),
        array(
            'role' => 'button',
            'class' => 'btn btn-success',
            'disabled' => 'disabled',
            'escape' => false
        )
    );

?>
```

Comment: This code does not work for me, the part $this-> HTML-> link shows a normal button available. Then I used a normal button from the form.